# git clone without history using SCM

Tags: git, jenkins-pipeline

Our project is huge and we would like to avoid cloning all git history.

Is it possible to `git clone` passing `depth=1` using `checkout scm` in Jenkins?

I cannot find any documentation about how to configure `SCM` or how to pass arguments, if possible.

*Added:*
Found the documentation

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#code-checkout-code-general-scm

> Type: int
>   **depth (optional)**
>   Set shallow clone depth, so that git will only download recent history of the 
>   project, saving time and disk space when you just want to access the latest 
>   version of a repository.

but it's not clear how to pass it to `checkout scm`

Comment: JFYI: if Jenkins has free executors on the node, it tries to re-use it instead of running the build on a random node. So most likely if you clone the repo once, it will be re-used next time. With time all your nodes (unless you clean them up) will have your Git repo and there won't be many full clones.

Comment: Ok, but in case of `branch=develop`, we remove the entire build dir before cloning.

Comment: I don't know why you would do this. Jenkins clears what needs to be cleared and there is no need to re-clone the repository. If you don't trust Jenkins - you can run `git reset --hard` and `git clean` on your own. This will be much faster than a shallow clone.

Comment: Yea right and my fail, build dir has nothing to do with checkout dir

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use scripted pipeline then you can customize `checkout scm` to look more or less like this:

```groovy
node {
    checkout([
        $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: scm.branches,
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
        extensions: scm.extensions,
        userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs,
        depth: 1
    ])
}
```

If you use the declarative pipeline, then you need to go to your pipeline job configuration and in the **Behaviors** section you need to add **Git -> Advanced clone behaviors** and mark **Shallow clone** and set **Shallow clone depth** to `1`.

[image]