# Getting wrong value of number of commits

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, artifactory, commit

```
def generateVersion() {
    def commitCount = sh(script: "git rev-list --count HEAD", returnStdout: true).trim() as Integer
    echo "this is commitcount------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ${commitCount}";
    def metadata = readJSON file: 'package.json'
    def (major, minor) = metadata.version.tokenize('.')
    def patch = commitCount
    def prerelease = env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ? '' : "-${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
    return "${major}.${minor}.${patch}${prerelease}"
}
```

This is a groovy code that I have written in my Jenkinsfile. It is supposed to return me a unique version of the build. This function gets called in a stage Publish Libraries.

```
....
stage('Publish Libraries') {
            dir('External') {
                libVersion = generateVersion()
...
...
```

I am not able to get the correct value of commitCount and therefore wrong value of patch. It stays consistent at value 5 no matter how many commits I make in my branch. I have created a branch off of another feature branch that initally had 56 commits. So when i created a branch it initally had those 56 commits. I added 11 commits of my own in the newly created branch so a total of 67 commits are there in the branch but it shows the count as only 5. What should I do?

I even tried:

```
def commitCount = sh(script: "git rev-list --count ${env.BRANCH_NAME}", returnStdout: true).trim() as Integer
```

thinking that maybe my HEAD gets set to some other branch without my knowledge. But still commitCount is 5.

Comment: If you split the first line into 2 operations. just get the string, print it out with `echo "Commit test was '$commitCountString'", and _then_ do `as Integer`, what does it print out?

Comment: How is your clone operation configured?

Comment: @tim_yates I split them up, but both are 5 and 5 still

Answer (score -1):

You're almost certainly using a *shallow clone* with `--depth=5` (and the corresponding implied `--single-branch`).  In this case, the revisions counted by `git rev-list HEAD` will never exceed five.  To fix the problem, tell Jenkins to use a non-shallow clone (see [git clone without history using SCM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56870219/1256452)).

Note that `--count` is not a reliable way to get a unique revision specifier even if you make a full (non-shallow) clone.  The reason is simple enough: the number of commits reachable from some branch tip does not necessarily increase (e.g., `git reset` *removes* commits from the branch tip), and the number of commits reachable from, e.g., `feature/a` and from `feature/b` may be the same:

```
          o--o   <-- feature/1
         /
...--o--o   <-- main
         \
          o--o   <-- feature/b
```

Here, let's say that the revision count found by starting from `main` and working backwards is 200.  There are two commits on each feature branch that are *not* on `main`, plus the 200 commits that *are* on `main`, so the count on both branches will be 202.  Yet the commits on `feature/a` differ from the commits on `feature/b`.

If you want a unique descriptive name for a commit that's at least marginally less ugly than a raw hash ID, consider using `git describe` (perhaps with `--always` and/or `--dirty`).  To make it work *well*, be sure to use tags (preferably annotated tags for releases) and maybe add the `--tags` option.